# Breaking equations in cases environment

Tags: equations, cases

Similar questions have been asked before, but my problem is a little different:

```
\begin{equation}
E_K \approx
\begin{cases}
- \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{N} K_1 \bri \left( \mathbf{m \bri} \cdot \unit{u} \bri \right)^2 V_i & \text{(Uniaxial)} \\
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{N} [ K_1 \bri \left( m_x^2 \bri m_y^2 \bri + m_y^2 \bri m_z^2 \bri + m_x^2 \bri m_z^2 \bri \right) \\ \qquad + K_2 m_x^2 \bri m_y^2 \bri m_z^2 \bri ] Vi & \text{(Cubic)}
\end{cases} \text{.}
\end{equation}
```

The above code produces an output as shown below:

[image]

The description of the second case is not in the middle. How do I fix this? Also, I should have used `\left[`...`\right]` instead of `[`...`]`. But, that produces an error.

Comment: It produces an error because they are not on the same line. Use `\bigl[`...`\bigr]` instead.

Answer (score 10):

You could place the long expression following the second summation symbol in an `array` structure.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'dcases' environment
\newcommand\bri{(\mathbf{r}_i)}
\newcommand\unit[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{equation}
E_K \approx
\begin{dcases}
- \sum_{i = 1}^{N} K_1 \bri \bigl( \mathbf{m \bri} \cdot \unit{u} \bri \bigr)^2 V_i & \text{(Uniaxial)} \\
\begin{array}{l} 
\displaystyle
\smash[b]{\sum_{i = 1}^{N}} 
\Bigl[ K_1 \bri \bigl( m_x^2 \bri m_y^2 \bri \\
\qquad{}+ m_y^2 \bri m_z^2 \bri 
+ m_x^2 \bri m_z^2 \bri \bigr) \\ 
\qquad{}+ K_2 m_x^2 \bri m_y^2 \bri m_z^2 \bri 
\Bigr] V_i 
\end{array}& \text{(Cubic)}
\end{dcases} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want the second "case" to be split across just two lines, you could do something like the following; note the use of `\phantom{-}` to line up the two summation symbols:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\bri{(\mathbf{r}_i)}
\newcommand\unit[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{equation}
E_K \approx
\begin{dcases}
- \sum_{i = 1}^{N} K_1 \bri \bigl[ \mathbf{m \bri} \cdot \unit{u} \bri \bigr]^2 V_i & \text{(Uniaxial)} \\
\begin{array}{@{}l} 
\displaystyle
\phantom{{}-}
\sum_{i = 1}^{N}
\bigl[ K_1 \bri \bigl( m_x^2 \bri m_y^2 \bri + m_y^2 \bri m_z^2 \bri \\
\qquad{}
+ m_x^2 \bri m_z^2 \bri \bigr) 
+ K_2 m_x^2 \bri m_y^2 \bri m_z^2 \bri 
\bigr] V_i 
\end{array}& \text{(Cubic)}
\end{dcases} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Mico. I stole some code from you ;-) Hope you don't mind. :-)

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `aligned`. I borrowed the `\smash` idea from Mico.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\bri}{(\mathbf{r}_{i})}
\newcommand*{\unit}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
E_K \approx
\begin{cases}
- \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{N} K_1 \bri \left( \mathbf{m \bri} \cdot \unit{u} \bri \right)^2 V_i & \text{(Uniaxial)} \\
\begin{aligned}
&\smash[b]{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{N}} \big[ K_1 \bri \big( m_x^2 \bri m_y^2 \bri + m_y^2 \bri m_z^2 \bri  \\
&\qquad{}+ m_x^2 \bri m_z^2 \bri \big) \\ 
&\qquad{}+ K_2 m_x^2 \bri m_y^2 \bri m_z^2 \bri \big] Vi\end{aligned}& \text{(Cubic)}
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Same thing works for two lines also. Again borrowing from Mico:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\bri{(\mathbf{r}_i)}
\newcommand\unit[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{equation}
E_K \approx
\begin{cases}
- \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{N} K_1 \bri \bigl[ \mathbf{m \bri} \cdot \unit{u} \bri \bigr]^2 V_i & \text{(Uniaxial)} \\[3ex]
\begin{aligned}
&\phantom{{}-}\smash[b]{\sum_{i = 1}^{N}}
\bigl[ K_1 \bri \bigl( m_x^2 \bri m_y^2 \bri + m_y^2 \bri m_z^2 \bri \\[1ex]
&\qquad{}+ m_x^2 \bri m_z^2 \bri \bigr)
+ K_2 m_x^2 \bri m_y^2 \bri m_z^2 \bri
\bigr] V_i
\end{aligned}& \text{(Cubic)}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the space @Mico has managed to set between the two capital sigmas.  Do you think you can fix it to look like Mico's?

Comment: @MarioS.E. It is easy `\\[3ex]`. Fixed.